# Build library targeting different API then main module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a library project based on a webview. It targets API 18 because I need a stable library that will not depend on webview updates (from API 19 webview updates independently) and will keep working correctly.

But because of that my main module have to target API 18 too. If I use higher target API, my library will automatically target it and can be broken on next updates.

Is it possible to build library targeting different API then the main module? For example main module targets API 23 and library targets API 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to build library targeting different API then the main module? 
>   For example main module targets API 23 and library targets API 18.

It doesn't make sense.

The final application has only one target defined in the Manifest file.
You haven't single modules inside your apk.